# Скопировать баннер

Tags: bootstrap, html, css

Наверное совсем не по ТЕМЕ, но все же. В общем есть сайт http://mbi-shop.ru, у него есть серая полоса с информацией (телефон и email и кнопки регистрации и авторзации), так вот, нужно его скопировать на другой сайт, но я не знаю как этот самый код взять оттуда.
На один сайт я его вставил спокойной, т.к он использует bootstrap, а на другом сайте бутстрапа нет, что же делать?
Кто нибудь может полностью скопировать код данного баннера прямо с бутстрапом? Скрин баннера: [КЛИК](http://f3.s.qip.ru/3GS55iCe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
        <a style="color:#333;font-size:16px;line-height:32px;font-weight:bold" href="/info/contact">+7 800 77 51 087</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span4" style="line-height:12px">
         <div><a style="color:#333;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold" href="/info/contact">Звонок по России бесплатный</a>
         </div>
    <div>
        <a style="color:#333;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold" href="mailto:post@mbi-mebel.ru">post@mbi-mebel.ru</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span6 usernav"><i class="icon-check"></i> <a href="/register">Зарегистрироваться</a> &nbsp; <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/login"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Войти в личный кабинет</a> </div></div>
```

Где у Вас тут возникли сложности?

Comment: Эм, а css?

Comment: Открываете стили бутсрапа и/или тех стилей что представлены на сайте, находите интересующие вас элементы ( row, span2, span4, usernav, etc...) копируете css. В чём сложности?